# How can I use jQuery "load" to perform a GET request with extra parameters?

Tags: jquery, parameters, load, http-get

I'm reading the [jQuery load documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) and it mentions that I can use load to perform a GET request by passing in extra parameters as a string.  My current code with my parameters as key/value pair is:

```
$("#output").load(
    "server_output.html",
    {
        year: 2009,
        country: "Canada"
    }
);
```

The above works fine but it's a post request.  How can I modify the above to perform a GET request while still using `load`?

Comment: Surround your data object with $.param() 
$("#output").load("server_output.html", $.param({year: 2009, country: "Canada"}));

Comment: @BastiaanLinders You should mark this as a full answer. It should be combined with the accepted answer which does not describe how to create the params string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the documentation you linked:

> A GET request will be performed by
>   default - but if you pass in any extra
>   parameters in the form of an
>   Object/Map (key/value pairs) then a
>   POST will occur. Extra parameters
>   passed as a string will still use a
>   GET request.

So the simple solution is to convert your object to a string before passing it to the function.  Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't specify the format the string should be in, but I would guess it would be the same as if you were generating the GET request manually.

```
$("#output").load(
    "/server_output.html?year=2009&country=Canada"
);
```

Answer (score 105):

Use `$.param(data)`:

```
$("#output").load(
    "server_output.html?" + $.param({
        year: 2009,
        country: "Canada"})
);
```

Comment: This really should be the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#output").load("server_output.html?year=2009&country=Canada");
```

Answer (score -1):

can you not just do:

```
$("#output").load(
    "server_output.html?year=2009&country='Canada'"
);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this

```
$("#output").load("server_output.html", {"2009":year, "Canada":country});
```

Comment: This is POST request